# Grouping and aggregating a big DataFrame using groupby and unstack to simplify and produce table for excel

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

**NB! New/extended question to my first question. I have added it in the bottom together with a picture of the end result I'm after**

I'm trying to simplify a dataset so that I can save some simple and easy to read tables in Excel. I started out with a small chunk of the excel data I want to work with to try out the code. It worked out:`Stor = pd.read_excel('Stortest')`
[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIdFy.png)
Then I tried an even bigger chunk and the code still worked out: `Stor_gb = Stor.groupby(['ID-nr','Art','Ar']).agg({'Antall':'sum'})` Then i unstacked year (Ar)`Stor_gb.unstack(2)`
[wanted result as table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7I9r.png)

```
df.head(10).to_dict()
```

`{'Løpnr.': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8, 8: 9, 9: 10}, 'Enkeltlokalitet': {0: 'Store Torungen', 1: 'Store Torungen', 2: 'Store Torungen', 3: 'Store Torungen', 4: 'Store Torungen', 5: 'Store Torungen', 6: 'Store Torungen', 7: 'Store Torungen', 8: 'Store Torungen', 9: 'Store Torungen'}, 'ID-nr': {0: 'AS3', 1: 'AS3', 2: 'AS3', 3: 'AS3', 4: 'AS3', 5: 'AS3', 6: 'AS3', 7: 'AS3', 8: 'AS3', 9: 'AS3'}, 'Lokalitet': {0: 'Store torungen (L)', 1: 'Store torungen (L)', 2: 'Store torungen (L)', 3: 'Store torungen (L)', 4: 'Store torungen (L)', 5: 'Store torungen (L)', 6: 'Store torungen (L)', 7: 'Store torungen (L)', 8: 'Store torungen (L)', 9: 'Store torungen (L)'}, 'superlokalitet': {0: 'Triangelet', 1: 'Triangelet', 2: 'Triangelet', 3: 'Triangelet', 4: 'Triangelet', 5: 'Triangelet', 6: 'Triangelet', 7: 'Triangelet', 8: 'Triangelet', 9: 'Triangelet'}, 'Kommune': {0: 'Arendal', 1: 'Arendal', 2: 'Arendal', 3: 'Arendal', 4: 'Arendal', 5: 'Arendal', 6: 'Arendal', 7: 'Arendal', 8: 'Arendal', 9: 'Arendal'}, 'Ar': {0: 2017, 1: 2017, 2: 2017, 3: 2017, 4: 2017, 5: 2017, 6: 2017, 7: 2017, 8: 2017, 9: 2017}, 'Art': {0: 'Gråmåke', 1: 'Sildemåke', 2: 'Svartbak', 3: 'Fiskemåke', 4: 'Makrellterne', 5: 'Ærfugl', 6: 'Grågås', 7: 'Hv.kinngås', 8: 'Tjeld', 9: 'Siland'}, 'Antall': {0: 384, 1: 322, 2: 38, 3: 12, 4: 0, 5: 46, 6: 8, 7: 1, 8: 1, 9: 2}}`

When I finally tried the same code with the full DataFrame I got this huge error message. I'm a total beginner and don't know even where to troubleshoot:

> error message:

```
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-9-fe2aa1037853> in <module>
----> 1 Full_gb = Full.groupby(['ID- 
nr','Art','Ar']).agg({'Antall':'sum'})

C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py in aggregate(self, func, engine, 
engine_kwargs, *args, 
**kwargs)
947             )
948 
--> 949         result, how = self._aggregate(func, *args, **kwargs)
950         if how is None:
951             return result

C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\core\base.py in _aggregate(self, arg, *args, **kwargs)
414 
415                 try:
--> 416                     result = _agg(arg, _agg_1dim)
417                 except SpecificationError:
418 

C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\core\base.py in _agg(arg, func)
381                 result = {}
382                 for fname, agg_how in arg.items():
--> 383                     result[fname] = func(fname, agg_how)
384                 return result
385 

C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\core\base.py in _agg_1dim(name, how, subset)
365                         "nested dictionary is ambiguous in 
aggregation"
366                     )
--> 367                 return colg.aggregate(how)
368 
369             def _agg_2dim(how):

C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py in aggregate(self, func, engine, 
engine_kwargs, *args, 
**kwargs)
238 
239         if isinstance(func, str):
--> 240             return getattr(self, func)(*args, **kwargs)
241 
242         elif isinstance(func, abc.Iterable):

C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in sum(self, numeric_only, 
min_count)
1538     def sum(self, numeric_only: bool = True, min_count: int = 0):
1539         return self._agg_general(
-> 1540             numeric_only=numeric_only, min_count=min_count, 
alias="add", npfunc=np.sum
1541         )
1542 

C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in _agg_general(self, 
numeric_only, min_count, alias, 
npfunc)
1013 
1014         # apply a non-cython aggregation
-> 1015         result = self.aggregate(lambda x: npfunc(x, 
axis=self.axis))
1016         return result
1017 

C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py in aggregate(self, func, engine, 
engine_kwargs, *args, 
**kwargs)
254             if self.grouper.nkeys > 1:
255                 return self._python_agg_general(
--> 256                     func, *args, engine=engine, 
engine_kwargs=engine_kwargs, **kwargs
257                 )
258 

C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in _python_agg_general(self, 
func, engine, 
engine_kwargs, *args, **kwargs)
1090 
1091         if len(output) == 0:
-> 1092             return self._python_apply_general(f, 
self._selected_obj)
1093 
1094         if self.grouper._filter_empty_groups:

C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in _python_apply_general(self, 
f, data)
890             data after applying f
891         """
--> 892         keys, values, mutated = self.grouper.apply(f, data, 
self.axis)
893 
894         return self._wrap_applied_output(

C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\core\groupby\ops.py in apply(self, f, data, axis)
211             # group might be modified
212             group_axes = group.axes
--> 213             res = f(group)
214             if not _is_indexed_like(res, group_axes):
215                 mutated = True

C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in <lambda>(x)
1058         func = self._is_builtin_func(func)
1059         if engine != "numba":
-> 1060             f = lambda x: func(x, *args, **kwargs)
1061 
1062         # iterate through "columns" ex exclusions to populate 
output dict

C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in <lambda>(x)
1013 
1014         # apply a non-cython aggregation
-> 1015         result = self.aggregate(lambda x: npfunc(x, 
axis=self.axis))
1016         return result
1017 

<__array_function__ internals> in sum(*args, **kwargs)

C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site- 
packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims, 
initial, where)
2240 
2241     return _wrapreduction(a, np.add, 'sum', axis, dtype, out, 
keepdims=keepdims,
-> 2242                           initial=initial, where=where)
2243 
2244 

C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site- 
packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in _wrapreduction(obj, ufunc, method, 
axis, dtype, out, 
**kwargs)
83                 return reduction(axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out, 
**passkwargs)
84             else:
---> 85                 return reduction(axis=axis, out=out, 
**passkwargs)
86 
87     return ufunc.reduce(obj, axis, dtype, out, **passkwargs)

C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\core\generic.py in stat_func(self, axis, skipna, level, 
numeric_only, 
min_count, **kwargs)
11417             skipna=skipna,
11418             numeric_only=numeric_only,
> 11419             min_count=min_count,
11420         )
11421 

C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\core\series.py in _reduce(self, op, name, axis, skipna, 
numeric_only, 
filter_type, **kwds)
4234                 )
4235             with np.errstate(all="ignore"):
-> 4236                 return op(delegate, skipna=skipna, **kwds)
4237 
4238     def _reindex_indexer(self, new_index, indexer, copy):

C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\core\nanops.py in _f(*args, **kwargs)
69             try:
70                 with np.errstate(invalid="ignore"):
---> 71                     return f(*args, **kwargs)
72             except ValueError as e:
73                 # we want to transform an object array

C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\core\nanops.py in nansum(values, axis, skipna, 
min_count, mask)
507     elif is_timedelta64_dtype(dtype):
508         dtype_sum = np.float64
--> 509     the_sum = values.sum(axis, dtype=dtype_sum)
510     the_sum = _maybe_null_out(the_sum, axis, mask, values.shape, 
min_count=min_count)
511 

C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site- 
packages\numpy\core\_methods.py in _sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims, 
initial, where)
45 def _sum(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False,
46          initial=_NoValue, where=True):
---> 47     return umr_sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims, initial, 
where)
48 
49 def _prod(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False,

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Someone Please help me!

Update:
@Nk03 pretty much fixed the main issue, but the extra code for margins gave again some errors on the full DataFrame. I tried it on a small test df and then it worked, but margins only give totals for the full table. Is it possible/ how can I get totals for every single group like in this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLAFp.png)?

Comment: Can you add a sample input dataframe along with your expected output? you can use `df.head(10).to_dict()` ??

Comment: I added dict above

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can try:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index=['ID-nr', 'Art'], columns='Ar',
               values='Antall', aggfunc=sum, fill_value=0)
```

If you need total use margin:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index=['ID-nr', 'Art'], columns='Ar',
                    values='Antall', aggfunc=sum, fill_value=0, margins=True, margins_name='Total_birds')
```

Comment: I friggin love you! This saves me so much work. Is it possible to get a total row after each group separating the groups? (that is a sum of all the birds in each and every location/ID-nr?

Comment: thank you for your help. I tried your latest suggestion adding margins to the code, but ended up with some errors (index error ; index out of bounds ..and some more). Any ideas about these errors?

Comment: Posted an update above to your code example regarding margins